# iphone openGL error: expected '=', ',' ,';' ,'asm' ,or '_attribute_' before 'pyramidVertices'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Hey - just starting out trying to get some openGL into my iphone app and came across this error for this bit of code:

```
static const GLfloat pyramidVertices[] = { 
   0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  
  -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 
   1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  
   1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  
  -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f  
};
```

am I not including something I should be? Without this everything compiles fine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't imported gl.h which defines GLfloat.